# NSInternalInconsistencyException error & crash when scanning cardboard QR profile, Unity iOS cardboard app

Tags: ios, google-cardboard

I made a new project with Unity 4.6.4, imported google cardboard (I believe 0.5.1), and built a simple iOS project. The onboarding process where you scan your cardboard's QR code works fine. However, when I click the gear in the experience, and scan a QR code, the app crashes with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1
>   from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update'

stack trace shows it's coming from 'main'.

I followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started-ios to configue the XCode project after building from Unity.

Update: when I try with cardboard v0.5.0, I don't have any problems.

Comment: Did you have the Sync With Cardboard option enabled or disabled?

Comment: pretty sure Sync with Cardboard is off.

Comment: I thought this bug was fixed in 0.5.1, but it might have regressed.  It happens when Sync With Cardboard is off, because there is one less row in the Settings dialog's table then.  If you can, try enabling Sync With Cardboard (see the Getting Started site for instructions), and see if the bug still happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this pod https://github.com/Itheme/SmartUITableViewPod to make UITableView exceptions non-fatal.

Just replace class for problematic UITableView in storyboards or xibs to SmartUITableView.